# How does web crawlers build directories of URLs to scrape contents needed

Tags: web, web-scraping, web-crawler, search-engine

I'm trying to understand how web crawling works. There are 3 questions:

1. Do we have to have an initial directory of URLs to build a larger
   directory of URLs? How does this work?
2. Are there any open source
       web crawlers written in python?
3. Where is the best place to learn more about web
           crawlers?

Answer (score 0):

Answering your second question first; [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) is a great tool to do web scraping in python.

When using it there are a number of ways to start the spiders. The CrawlSpider can be given a list of initial URLs to start from. It then scrapes these pages looking for new links which are added to the queue of pages to search.

Another way to use it is with the sitemap spider. For this spider you give the crawler a list of the URLs of websites sitemaps. The spider then looks up the list of pages from the sitemap and crawls those.